# Referencing an input variable in another input variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.8

As an intermediate python developer, I have attempted to solve a problem which simulates a virtual library. I essentially need to ask the user for their name and the number of books they have read.

My input must look something like this:

```
name = str(input("Enter name: ")))
booksRead = int(input("Number of books", *name variable* "read: "))
```

Unfortunately, I cannot seem to find any way to reference my name variable within my booksRead variable (obviously python does not allow you to reference variables within input prompters).

Is there any way I can achieve the same result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use :

```
booksRead = int(input(f"Number of books {name} read: "))
```

https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#pep-498-formatted-string-literals

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings

Comment: f-string is def my prefered approach these days makes things look cleaner and more readable

Comment: Gotta agree with you there

Answer (score 2):

So there is multiple possible solutions, one of them is what **Loïc** suggested

another option is using `format`:

```
booksRead = int(input("Number of books {:} read: ".format(name)))
```

another option is using `%s`:

```
booksRead = int(input("Number of books %s read: " % name))
```

all are equivalent

Comment: agreed, those options also work, but I must say I'm fond of f-string formatting :D

Comment: Completely forgot about the new string format, thanks for the help and providing some other options, much appreciated.